# Prove that this function interpolates function in $x_0, x_1,..., x_n$

Tags: interpolation

Let $q\in \prod_{n-1}$ be interpolation polynomial for $x_1,...,x_n$ and $p\in \prod_{n-1}$ be interpolation polynomial for $x_0,...,x_{n-1}$. Show that function
$$N(x)=q(x)\left( 1+\frac{x_n-x}{x_0-x_n}\right) -  \frac{x_n-x}{x_0-x_n}p(x)$$
is interpolation polynomial for $x_0,...,x_n$.

My idea was to represent $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ as Lagrange polynomials. Hence
$$q(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nf(x_k)\prod_{i=1 \\ i \neq k}^n\frac{x-x_i}{x_k-x_i}$$
$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}f(x_k)\prod_{i=0 \\ i \neq k}^{n-1}\frac{x-x_i}{x_k-x_i}$$
and just write it in
$$N(x)=q(x) +  \frac{x_n-x}{x_0-x_n}(q(x)-p(x))$$
but I'm stuck and feel like this not the right way to do it. Any ideas?

I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956968/g-h-interpolates-f-at-x-0-ldots-x-n-1-x-1-ldots-x-n-then-g) although I'm curious if one can do this with Lagrange.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this harder than it needs to be.

What you need to show, if I am interpreting your statements correctly, is that
$N(x)
=p(x)
$
for
$x=x_0,...,x_{n-1}$
and
$N(x)
=q(x)
$
for
$x=x_1,...,x_{n}$.

If $p$ and $q$
interpolate to the same values,
you need to have
$p(x)
=q(x)
$
for
$x=x_1,...,x_{n-1}$.

This should be enough.

Comment: $x_0,...,x_n$ are the same for $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ so I don't see how $N(x)=p(x)$ and $N(x)=q(x)$

Comment: I assume you want to do something similar to the answer in the question I linked - for now, it seems the most reasonable way to do it